# What is the reference Kanbara made in episode 4 of Kyoukai no Kanata: Mini Theater special?

Tags: japanese-language, beyond-the-boundary

At 01:53 of episode 4 of Kyoukai no Kanata: Mini Theater special, after Hiroomi said that Mitsuki was his only idol, this conversation happened (transcribed to the best of my ability):

> **Kanbara:** おい、博臣{ひろおみ}、そろそろやめとけよ。美月{みつき}がＭＫ[５]｛ご｝だぞ。
>
> **Kuriyama:** メガ盛｛も｝り 金平ごぼう、　ですか？
>
> **Kanbara:** そっ、それ、マジ？

If my guesses are right, Kuriyama mistook MK5 (emu-kei-go) as abbreviation for **M**egamori (large serving) **K**inpira<sup>1</sup> **Go**bou<sup>2</sup>, which is a Japanese dish.

<sup><sup>1</sup> A Japanese style of cooking. [ja.Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E5%B9%B3). [en.Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinpira).</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Burdock. [ja.Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%9C%E3%82%A6). [en.Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctium_lappa).</sup>

[image]

<sup>Image from http://cookpad.com/recipe/1743175</sup>

My question is about "MK5" in Kanbara's line. While the line can be generally understood as Mitsuki was getting pissed off at Hiroomi, I don't get what Kanbara is making a reference of by saying "MK5". Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"MK5" means "[maji kireru 5 byoumae](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1447224064)" ([マジで切れる５秒前](http://zokugo-dict.com/04e/mk5.htm)), or being on the verge of losing it ([really pissed off](http://www.pixiv.net/tags.php?tag=MK5(%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AC%E3%82%8B5%E7%A7%92%E5%89%8D))).